# The Scutoid, a new shape

Tags: polyhedra, solid-geometry, tiling, biology

The [scutoid](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05376-1) ([Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05376-1), [Gizmodo](https://gizmodo.com/the-scutoid-is-geometrys-newest-shape-and-it-could-be-1827924643), [New Scientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2175297-a-new-shape-called-the-scutoid-has-been-discovered-in-our-cells/), [eurekalert](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2018-07/lu-srn072418.php)) is a newly defined shape found in epithelial cells. It's a 5-prism with a truncated vertex.  The g6 format of the graph is KsP`?_HCoW?T .

[image: Scutoid]

They are apparently a building block for living creatures. One simple set of vertices that look reasonable with planar faces is {{2,4,0},{0,4,2},{0,2,4},{2,0,4},{4,0,2},{4,2,0},{1,3,6},{3,1,6},{6,6,2},{4,16,14}/3,{16,4,14}/3,{5,5,0}}.

[image: scutoid]

What other mathematical properties do scutoids have?  For example:

1. Under what fixed parameters is the polyhedron a space-filler?
2. If curved faces are allowed, are there more single-shape space-fillers?
3. Is there a nice lattice representation with just a few different types of scutoid cells?
4. What is the scutoid-building algorithm used by DNA?

Using code at [Canonical Polyhedra](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CanonicalPolyhedra/), a canonical form looks like

[image: canonical scutoid]

Comment: Are you interested in the physical shape or the abstract polyhedron? The diagrams clearly suggest curved edges, and arguably 'concave' and 'convex' varieties of the shape.

Comment: . . . nice . . .

Comment: Both the physical shape and the abstract.

Answer (score 3):

The green-yellow pic of yours looks like being interested in a stacking of layers. Then you would require a vertex layer of pentagons and hexagons, which just flips from one layer to the next those 2 shapes. And the medial vertex layer in between would intersect those shapes in a tiling with pentagonal shapes only. - Neither of those is possible to be done by regular polygons only.

As an aside one might add so, that these shapes look like a hybrid mixture of a prism and a cupola, thereby replacing the medial vertex by the simplex spanned by the neighbouring vertices each. - Sure, that derived space-filling then no longer uses just a single cell type, but might be considered easier non the less, as there are no additional vertex layers in between.

--- rk

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer only. According to mathematician [Laura Taalman](https://www.jmu.edu/mathstat/people/faculty-full-time/Taalman-Laura.shtml) of James Madison University in her discussion after about `06:40` in the Standupmaths video [THE SCUTOID: did scientists discover a new shape?](https://youtu.be/2_NZ1ql8B8Y?t=401), *it is not a polyhedron as it indeed has several curved faces.*